# How to change Nav bar font colors (ASP.NET)

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio

I am currently trying to create a web-based page by creating a new, default ASP.NET Web Application (.Net Framework) and I found out that I can change the colour of the navigation bar by adding the following code to the "Site.css" in the content file.

```
.navbar-inverse {
background-color: #74D6FF;
border-color: #74D6FF;
}
```

I also know that I can change the text for all the different text tabs within the navigation bar by modifying the Site.Master.

The one thing that I have not figured out is how to change the color of the text within the navigation bar? May anyone assist me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Current active page:**

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    color: #xxxxxx;
}
```

**Current active page (on hover):**

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
    color: #xxxxxx;
}
```

**Other pages:**

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #xxxxxx;
}
```

**Other pages (on hover):**

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    color: #xxxxxx;
}
```

Comment: Adding the following section of code seemed to change the colors for the text of the tabs on the nav bar, but it did not change the color of the main / first button.

    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
        color: #xxxxxx;
    }


https://gyazo.com/7b2eeb38c75360afc5c40e81977a002b

Comment: Hard for me to help without seeing the code. Do you know how to use your browser's developer tools (F12)? You can select the element and see which CSS class it's using.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with ASP.NET, but are you just changing the font color with css?
then this should work.

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #74D6FF;
    border-color: #74D6FF;
    color: #VALUE;
}
```